# GAE-Development-Server: How to exclude part of the code from beeing checked for restricted classes?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to try a new Jvm-language (yeti-lang) on app-engine.

To have a more rapid development, there is a ServletFilter which in development-mode, watches the yeti-source dir and recompiles the yeti-sources on each change automatically and than uses them to handle the rquest. (During production the sources are compile by the buildscript and the filter does nothing).

This works well on normal Servlet-Containers however the gae-development-server complains about using a restricted class (java nio.file.Filesystem which is used to watch the source-dir for changes), which is generally fine. However in this case it would be great if I could just take this DevlopmentFilter out of the restricted-class check or somehow work around it.

Is there any way to accomplisch that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have any of your GAE/J code outside of the GAE/J whitelist, whether it is in production or on a dev app server, so you cannot use `java.nio.file.FileSystem` within your GAE/J application.

As to a workaround, can you accomplish what you want to do (excluding writing to the GAE/J file system, which is not allowed in GAE/J) using other Java file classes (for example: `java.io.File`)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could use java.io.File to scan for source-changes. However for recompilation of the class files must be write to the filesystem (only in dev-mode).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could use java.io.File to scan for source-changes. However for recompilation of the class files must be write to the filesystem (only in dev-mode). I was looking at the com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory#createDevAppServer() methods, which seems to have a method to start the server without security. Is that useable? I was also looking at the play-framework gae module. They seem to make their own Delegate and set it on the com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy und use their own webserver. Maybe I'll try this route?

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot help you on these matters; I have never used `DevAppServerFactory` methods or the play-framework GAE module.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it now is to add true to appengine-web.xml. This seems to turn off the checking for restricted classes.

However I'd prefer a System-Property or somehting which I can set when launching the dev-server to turn on/off whitelist-checking. As I do not want to deploy an appengine-web.xml with  this tag.

Comment: You forgot to finish writing your first paragraph.